# How to display text in one line in table?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the logo, price and button on an even line but I can not do it in any way.

I'm Trying to give the same margin-top - when I manage to set in an even line, in the desktop version is ok - but it looks a bit different on the mobile.

Also I cannot change location for:

```
.pc_vendor-offers .pc_action {
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 27px;
}
```

I added:  `margin-top: 27px;` but the button still stays in place prnt.sc/n1n9my

```
   .price-comparison-container {
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.price-comparison {
  border-top: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.pc_title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.pc_arrow-up, .pc_arrow-down {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.pc_arrow-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #FFF;
  top: 2px;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR9Nl.png)

here is full code (due to the limit)
https://zabezcen.pl/fullcode.html

Comment: This is not a [minimum, complete & verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I corrected my subject. I could not add all the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an `HTML` problem, but a `CSS` problem.
this is not the code causing the problem , u need to provide the CSS part.

Create two rules that they apply alternate margins at different screen resolutions. More on media queries [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

```css
  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .pc_logo, .pc_offer, .pc_action {
      margin-top: 25%;
    }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .pc_logo, .pc_offer, .pc_action {
      margin-top: 10%;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Edit : Good now we have the css Part .

Comment: @Daniel, last thing. Can you please check: `.pc_action` is responsible for button "Przejdź do sklepu". Here I add also margin-top: 27px;
 but he stands still. I can not change  location this button in any way. Also on desktop and mobile. https://prnt.sc/n1n9my

Comment: just add !important; to the rule 
.pc_action{
margin-top : 27px!important;
}
More Information :
[important]:https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/